# When I am loading data from file to db2 database for timestamp datatype having only date portion in it, will db2 automatically add time details in it

Tags: db2

When I am loading data from file to db2 database for timestamp datatype having only date portion in it, will db2 automatically add time details in it.

I had a file with only the date format. Still data got loaded but while querying data has default time portion as well like 10/22/1969 12:00:00.000000 AM ?
Is this by default?

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2-server?  Z/OS, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows ?   For Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows the default value for the time part of the timestamp would be all zeroes (not 12.00.00.000000 as you show).

Comment: What tool do you use for data loading?

Comment: @mao 12:00 AM is 00:00, i.e. all zeroes.

Comment: @mustaccio  Doh! I did'nt see the AM.

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` format includes the date and time, so internally it must be stored stored as a binary structure that contains more data than just the date, see:

```
db2 "describe values current date" 

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 384   DATE                     10  1                                         1
```

vs.

```
db2 "describe values current timestamp" 

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 392   TIMESTAMP                26  1                                         1
```

You can even examine actual structure byte-by-byte with the [`HEX()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000811.html) function:

```
db2 "values hex(date(current timestamp))"

1       
--------
20191013

db2 "values hex(timestamp(current timestamp))"

1                   
--------------------
20191013090443204348
```

Depending on the utility used, Db2 will implicitly cast the values to TIMESTAMP target. With LOAD, you can see the [documentation for timestampformat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) to see what formats will be accepted by default.

Assuming Db2 LUW, I did a quick test with:

```
db2 "create table timestamp_load_test(c1 int, c2 timestamp)"
echo "1,2019-10-13-09.00.00.000000" >> data.del
echo "2,2019-10-13-09.00.00"        >> data.del
echo "3,2019-10-13-09.00"           >> data.del
echo "4,2019-10-13"                 >> data.del

db2 "load from data.del of del replace into timestamp_load_test nonrecoverable"
...
SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is 
incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007
SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row "F0-3" of 
the input file.
...
Number of rows read         = 4
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows loaded       = 3
Number of rows rejected     = 1
Number of rows deleted      = 0
Number of rows committed    = 4
```

As we can see, 3 rows were accepted:

```
db2 "select * from timestamp_load_test"

C1          C2                        
----------- --------------------------
          1 2019-10-13-09.00.00.000000
          2 2019-10-13-09.00.00.000000
          4 2019-10-13-00.00.00.000000
```

Of course they are displayed with time portion but actual formatting will depend on the client used.